# HTML Simple Form Text Input Style

Tags: html, css

Hey guys i was just wondering how to do this in a input type of text
when the user has not click the box. show "Edit Name" in the box with a slightly grey font color.
When the user clicks in the box it changes to "John Doe" and then they can edit it then submit

//EDIT
 doesn't work as it already has a value set. i need the placeholder to show until clicked then the value shows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using HTML5 the [Placeholder attribute](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder) is the way to go.

If not just grab one of the many watermark scripts out there for jQuery or Javascript (e.g. [jQuery Watermark](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/).

**EDIT**

One manual way to do what you want with jQuery and CSS:

```
// CSS 
#name{color:#ccc;}

// HTML
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" value="Edit Name" />

// jQuery
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#name').bind('focus', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'Edit Name') {
      $(this).val('John Doe').css('color', '#000');
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Put the `jQuery` section in the code above into the `<head>` section of your HTML document and you should be good to go.

Comment: <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" value="Hawks"  placeholder="Team Name"/> doesn't work as it already has a value set. i need the placeholder to show until clicked then the value shows

Comment: Thank you so much, but i have never used jQuery before, how would i include it in my script? <script> tags?

Comment: Thanks! i have put the jquery in my <head> tags inside the <script tages you have posted but it is not working? :(

Comment: Got it sorted :D thankyou, how would i include a php variable in the John Doe part?

Comment: When you're outputting you `<input>` tag just use `value="<?php echo $the_value; ?>"`

Answer (score 0):

Newer browsers support the HTML5 `placeholder` attribute, which you can use as follows:

```
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="Edit Name">
```

For browsers that don't support it, [various](http://www.morethannothing.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/placeholder.js) [fallback](http://thomas.vondeyen.com/2011/02/22/html5-forms-placeholder-fallback/) [scripts](http://unwrongest.com/projects/defaultvalue/) exist, which will automatically do their work if the attribute isn't supported.

Dive into HTML5 has [a table](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#placeholder) of which browser versions support it natively, in case you're interested.

Comment: <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" value="Hawks" placeholder="Team Name"/> doesn't work as it already has a value set. i need the placeholder to show until clicked then the value shows